# Example of an Affine space

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition

let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be some fairly simple polynomial functions. I let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be some elements of the set of their respective antiderivatives.

Now, can I say that the set of ordered pairs $\left(F_1, F_2\right)$ is an affine space with corresponding vector space $\mathbb{R^2}$.
it does seem to satisfy all the axioms of affine space and seems a good example intuitively as there is no preferable antiderivative.